# Led him to/into behaving childishly

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about the usage of "***led somebody to doing something***" and "***led somebody into doing something***":

> 1. His young age ***led*** him ***to*** behaving childishly.
> 2. His young age ***led*** him ***into*** behaving childishly.

Does "***led .. to***" have different meanings from "***led ... into***"?

Comment: The past tense of **lead** is *led*.

Comment: **to behave** and **into behaving**.

Comment: @TRomano This peeve is **_my_** pet! +1

Comment: @meatie At first glance the only difference seems to be in the distinction between the prepositions _in_ and _into._ However, [**Cambridge**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/lead-to-sth) calls _lead to_ a phrasal with the meaning _cause sth to happen or exist. _Lead into_ conveys the sense of physically preceding someone or sth. So your first sentence (with, as TRomano points out, the bare infinitive) is grammatical and idiomatic; the second may be technically grammatical, but it is not idiomatic at all.

Answer (score 1):

More naturally, when one thing leads to another, and you have structured the sentence as "adjective-noun" leads to X, the sentence is better understood as "adjective-noun" leads to "adjective-noun".  Composing the sentence as "adjective-noun" leads to "verb-adverb", sounds unnatural.

> His young age led to his childish behavior.

or more simply

> His young age led to childish behavior.

Comment: This also keeps the components of the phrasal next to each other, where they are most comfortable.